# Vue should I stop hard coding endpoints in .env?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, frontend, vue-cli

I've read an article about [How to Stop Hardcoding Service Endpoints in Vue.js](http://www.bigendiandata.com/2020-01-13-Vue_for_S3/)

What's your thought on it?

is there's a better way to do this? or should I continue on  environment variables using `.env` file?

right now my  environment variables in a project’s `.env` file looks like :

```
ENVIRONMENT=local
API_URL=http://localhost:8080/
API_VER=/api/v1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of the article is that if you have a library/package then, at run time, because of bundling, you lose the ability to change the endpoints easily.

Although that's true, it is hard to find a use case when this actually happens. Updating your endpoints and then doing a build is usually how to approach this and that's perfectly fine.

I think is perfectly fine to keep your endpoint in a config file that is consumed at compile time, instead of a runtime available one.

There may be perfectly valid reasons for using a runtime available config file, but this doesn't take away from having a compile time one.

Answer (score 1):

At the client-side, it's better to add "nonsensitive reusable information" on a config or environment file to avoid repeating and hardcoding things.

And it's impossible to hide secret information on the client-side so anything sensitive should be on the server.